# TestNG test suite execution time

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, testng

I found that test execution time is:

```
(Reporter.getCurrentTestResult().getEndMillis() - Reporter.getCurrentTestResult().getStartMillis()) / 1000
```

But i've got not readable result:

> -1476173903

How can i get readable result for my logging?

Comment: Looks like `Reporter.getCurrentTestResult().getEndMillis()` is returning zero. Have you looked at the documentation to see why that might be?

Comment: i'm looking for answer 2 days already (

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not try declaring a variable at the start of your test.
i.e
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

then after the test block.
long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

long executionTime = endTime - startTime;

to make it readable

TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(executionTime);